# Parsing text for analysis in R

Tags: r, parsing, text, dplyr, tidytext

I have a .txt file that includes short articles, and I want to use R to create a data set that parses each article and extracts the date, author, journal, title, line number, and text for each line of text in each article in a data frame. For example, the text data for each article repeats the same structure and takes the following format:

```
This is a Title  
December 15, 2005 | Publisher  
Author: JANE DOE  
Section: Movies and More  
2554 Words
Page: C3  
OpenURL  
Link  

Text Text Text Text   
Another line of text  
One more thing  
End of article.   

Citation (asa Style)  
DOE, JANE. 2005. "This is a Title," Publisher, December 15, pp.C3.

Different Title  
December 18, 2005 | Publisher  
Author: JOHN DOE  
Section: News 
662 Words
Page: C8  
OpenURL  
Link  

Here is more text   
It is still text
But also shorter.  

Citation (asa Style)  
DOE, JOHN. 2005. "Different Title," Publisher, December 18, pp.C8.
```

For each article, I want to extract the author, the data published, the journal, and each line to create a data frame that looks like this:

```
Date           Journal       Title             Author            Line              Text
15-Dec-2005    Publication   This is a title   Doe, Jane         1                 Text Text Text Text
15-Dec-2005    Publication   This is a title   Doe, Jane         2                 Another line of text
15-Dec-2005    Publication   This is a title   Doe, Jane         3                 One more thing
15-Dec-2005    Publication   This is a title   Doe, Jane         4                 End of article.
18-Dec-2005    Publication   Different Title   Doe, John         1                 Here is more text 
18-Dec-2005    Publication   Different Title   Doe, John         2                 It is still text
18-Dec-2005    Publication   Different Title   Doe, John         3                 But also shorter.
```

I want to use the code below to transform the data frame above (let's call it text_df) into tidy text format, restructured in a one-token-per-row format,

```
library(tidytext)
tidy_dat <- text_df %>%
  unnest_tokens(word, text)
```

I understand this is a big ask. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me. Can you load a few more examples?. You can use `read.delim` to read and create data.frame with one vector. Each line will be a row. Now you can just take the lines you want.

Comment: Essentially, I want to go through the text file and extract the content between "Link" and "Citation (asa Style)", line by line. But because I want to do this for many different sequential articles, and each of these lines of text correspond to a specific article, I also want to create new variables in that data.frame that show the article's title, author, data of publication, and journal (all contained in that one line of text after the "Citation" line). I could do it by hand, but there are so many articles and I wondered if there was an alternative...

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have many fields that you wish to extract, I created the main idea - from here you can follow :)

First, loading the `tidyverse` and the article:

```
library(tidyverse)
articles <- read.delim("C:/Your_Path/temp.txt",
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = FALSE)
```

We can use `grep` to get the positions of "Link" and "Citation" in the text.

```
positions <- grep(pattern = "Link|Citation", 
                 x = articles$V1)
```

Because Link always comes before Citation we can `split` the `positions` into a list of twos.

```
positions <- split(positions, ceiling(seq_along(positions)/2))
```

Now, we can extract the authors positions, using the same idea (`grep`).

```
authors <- grep(pattern = "Author", 
               x = articles$V1)
```

It's always good to check if your vectors/list are in the same length. That way, you can see if you extracted more authors than link and citation.

```
length(authors) == length(positions)
```

As I'm assuming you have more than two arguments to run with (text, authors, publishing, year, etc.), I use `purrr::pmap`. `pmap`, similarly to `map`/`map2` runs over one or more lists/vectors and preforms a function. In this case, the function takes (each time) the corresponding line the `articles` to `positions` and `author`

```
books <- purrr::pmap(
    list(positions, authors), 
  function(position, author) {
    cbind(
      data.frame(text = articles[seq(position[1] + 1, position[2] - 1, 1), ]),
      data.frame(author = articles[author,]))})
```

As `pmap` returns a `list`, we can bind the `data.frame`s within the list into one `data.frame`.

```
do.call(rbind.data.frame, books)
```

Result:

```
                      text             author
1.1 Text Text Text Text    Author: JANE DOE  
1.2 Another line of text   Author: JANE DOE  
1.3       One more thing   Author: JANE DOE  
1.4     End of article.    Author: JANE DOE  
2.1   Here is more text    Author: JOHN DOE  
2.2       It is still text Author: JOHN DOE  
2.3    But also shorter.   Author: JOHN DOE
```

Now, you can do whatever, `tidytext` analyses you want.

Comment: This is excellent. I appreciate the completeness in your explanations. I haven't yet attempted to add the additional variables, but I don't foresee a problem given your clarity. Thanks again!